# Vertically centering header and paragraph in html

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

I am still very new at all this, but I'm starting to learn. It seems there are many ways to vertically center my content, but I can't figure out how to apply it to the code I already have and to both my header and paragraph. I would like my h2 header and .why_text vertically centered. What's the best way to do this? Here is what I have so far. (Note that I will have 5 sections thus the odd/even)

```
<style><!--
p.large {
    line-height:30px;
    font-size:16px;
}
.why_section   {margin-bottom: 80px;}

      .why_section:nth-child(odd) h2 {display: block; width: 64%; margin-left: 5%; float: right;}
      .why_section:nth-child(odd) .why_image { width: 30%; margin-right:1%; float: left;}
      .why_section:nth-child(odd) .why_text {width: 64%; margin-left: 1%; float: right;}

      .why_section:nth-child(even) h2 {display: block; width: 64%; margin-left: 0%; float: left;}
      .why_section:nth-child(even) .why_image { width: 30%; margin-left:1%; float: right;}
      .why_section:nth-child(even) .why_text {width: 64%; margin-right: 5%; float: left;}

       .why_section .why_image img{ width: 100%;}

       .clear {clear: both;}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px)  {
            .why_section:nth-child(odd) h2 {display: block; width: 100%; margin-left: 0%; float: none;}
            .why_section:nth-child(odd) .why_image { width: 100%; margin-left: 0%; float: none;}
            .why_section:nth-child(odd) .why_text {width: 100%; margin-right: 0%; float: none;}

            .why_section:nth-child(even) h2 {display: block; width: 100%; margin-left: 0%; float: none;}
            .why_section:nth-child(even) .why_image { width: 100%; margin-left: 0%; float: none;}
            .why_section:nth-child(even) .why_text {width: 100%; margin-right: 0%; float: none;}
        }
--></style>
<div id="why_wrapper">
<div class="why_section">
<h2>...</h2>
<div class="why_image"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="why_text">
<p class="large">...</p>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a single line of text centred or a block of text?

Comment: Sorry, forgot this. I read this changes the approach. Block of text on all 5 sections. Header will only be a few words at most.

Comment: Are `vh` units an option in your case? For a single row of text, you can often use `line-height`, which will make a single line of text centred within the height you set for the line-height (assuming no margins or paddings). It's an effective solution for 1 line.  For multiple lines, you may need to mix top and bottom paddings and line-heights for your various css breakpoints to achieve a similar effect. If you want one 'panel' per screen, you can set your panel height to 100% and use the paddings and line-heights within that to balance your text (per section).

Comment: @user1522290, if you want to horizontaly position the P & H1(header) just wrapped them inside a div and create class then set the css [ '.centered { margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; } ']